# What to do when scholars are divided on an opinion?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-scholar

I wanted to know what to do when scholars are divided on an opinion? Sometimes whenever I search whether a thing is halal or haram, scholars are divided on the opinion, some say it's halal, some say it's makrooh and some says it's haram, so what should we do in this situation? Should we go with the choice which is most suitable for us? And will that person be punished if an action was haram to do

Comment: see also : https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/74471/etiquettes-of-reading-tafsir/74506#74506. I do not think that your question is duplicate to that one; good question +1

Answer (score -1):

It is necessary to mention a few points: 1. Usually and naturally in the theoretical issues of any field, the experts and scientists of that field disagree with each other on a series of issues, including ijtihad in the rules of religion. 2. The authorities do not differ from each other in all matters of religion. The difference of authority is in some details of the sub-sentences; Because in the doctrinal principles, generalities and general principles, the sub-rules such as the principle of prayer, fasting, Hajj ... and in many partial rules agree and do not differ. Due to the importance of ijtihad, which is the survival and continuity of the religion, Islam has ignored some of its minor effects, namely the occurrence of differences in some cases.
In such cases, it is better to follow a religious scholar who is scientifically superior. But if the action seems difficult for you according to that  scholar, you can follow the opinion of another  scholar so that you do not suffer.

https://www.makarem.ir/ahkam/fa/home/istifta/269705/%d9%88%d8%b8%d9%8a%d9%81%d9%87-%d9%85%d9%82%d9%84%d8%af-%d8%af%d8%b1-%d9%85%d8%b3%d8%a7%d9%8a%d9%84-%d8%a7%d8%ae%d8%aa%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%81%d9%8a

https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa3514